# ffmpeg Drawtext with timer not working

Tags: video, ffmpeg

ffmpeg Drawtext with timer not working.

Here's my CLI code:

```
ffmpeg -t 20 -i song.mp3 -i bluebg.jpg   -s "1280*720"  -movflags +faststart    -y vwithaudio.mp4 

ffmpeg -i vwithaudio.mp4 -vf "drawtext=enable='between(t,1,10)':fontsize=30:fontcolor=white:fontfile=pathtoofontfontfile.ttf: text='Test Text'" -acodec copy -y timerdemo.mp4
```

No errors displayed at console.

However, the text would not appear.

I noticed that in the first command if I use a `mp4` instead of `bluebg.jpg`, it works. So why cannot I use a background image for the first video so that drawtext timer works?

Would appreciate help from experts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first command, use

```
ffmpeg -t 20 -i song.mp3 -loop 1 -t 20 -i bluebg.jpg -s "1280*720" -movflags +faststart -y withaudio.mp4
```

A single image is treated as one frame, unless you loop it to create a video stream. So, in the 2nd command, the video only contains one frame, and between t 1 to 10, there are no frames to draw text over.

The `-t 20` is added to stop the loop when the duration of the audio is matched.

Comment: There should be a grey tick mark to the left of the answer. Click on that.